# Getting wrong input with ImageIO.read()

Tags: java, image, input

I am trying to make a program that encodes/decodes an image.

The idea: load -> encode/decode -> save

After running both encode and decode algorithms images comes out with missplaced pixels
and color loss.

I can ensure you that my encoding/decoding algorithms are working properly.
After decoding every pixel is put in the save exact location as it was before encoding.

Then I ran my program without encoding/decoding functions. It only opened file and then saved it.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;  

private BufferedImage img;
img = ImageIO.read(inputFile);
ImageIO.write(img, format, outputFile);
```

Here's a test input image:
[image]

And the corresponding output:
[image]

Column 5 witch was pure red turned into dark brown, orange turned into darker orange...etc..
Colors near red were effected the most.
Then I ran my programa again but this time I added this:

```
//4 because red was in the 5th column
System.out.println(img.getRGB(4, 4));
```

and I got integer with value

```
 -1237980
```

If I understand this correctly then the return should be more similar to

```
167116..
```

This means that error occurs during read()? What can I do about it? How do I avoid this?
Can you suggest some other libraries to do the job?

And yes, i tried different formats, color loss persists and with some bigger images pixel
missplacement happens(not because of encoding/decoding).

Comment: Not sure what you mean with “encode/decode”.  From my understanding, this is exactly what `ImageIO.read` and `ImageIO.write` do (only the other way round).  Anyway, in your code snippet, you have the variable `format`.  Are you sure it is the same format as the image was saved before?  Clearly, different image formats have different losses and converting between them almost certainly decreases quality.  Also: Could it be that the image's original format does not use RGB and some color transformation is taking place behind your back?